# DB sqlite throws me error database disk image is malformed

Tags: sql, sqlite

I am runinng code for inserting rows by chunks to sqlite db. Every time when i hit 1,5M then sqlite throws errno 11

> SQLITE_CORRUPT: database disk image is malformed
> at Query.formatError

I have table like this

```
CREATE TABLE table2_update (
    id  INT NOT NULL,
    checksum    text NOT NULL UNIQUE,
    to_update boolean default 1,
    PRIMARY KEY(id,checksum),
    UNIQUE KEY (id)
);
```

And i am running this query

```
INSERT INTO table2_update (id,checksum)
VALUES ('1500000','someuniquehash1')...('1600000','someuniquehash2')
ON CONFLICT (id,checksum) DO UPDATE SET to_update=0;
```

Every time i hit over 1,5M then application crash. I running this on local enviroment.